# VB6 activex runs only with administrative privileges

Tags: internet-explorer, vb6, activex

Several years ago we have written VB6 activex control that is hosted by a webpage.
Since then for many users it stopped working unless the user logged on with administrative privileges. The website is set to "Trusted sites" in IE. The IE security settings are the same 
for both *Admin* and *User*.
The control cab file is signed. 
The control implements IObjectSafety interface.
During cab file creation the Safe for scripting and initialization options are checked.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Are you trying to do anything to the user's computer that might require administrative priveliges?

Answer (score 1):

What does the control attempt to do locally?  Maybe it's trying to change privileged parts of the registry, or open devices directly—the sorts of things that only privileged programs are allowed to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely compatibility with Internet Explorer 8.   It implements SiteLock to restrict access per site/domain so that controls may only run from their point of installation by default. My guess is that your control is getting flagged as "never safe".

Recommended resources:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd433050(VS.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd433049(VS.85).aspx